# How to write a calculator using only functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Task: This time we want to write calculations using functions and get the results. Let's have a look at some examples:**

seven(times(five())) # must return 35

four(plus(nine())) # must return 13

eight(minus(three())) # must return 5

six(divided_by(two())) # must return 3

**Requirements:**

There must be a function for each number from 0 ("zero") to 9 ("nine")

There must be a function for each of the following mathematical operations: plus, minus, times, dividedBy (divided_by in Ruby and Python)

Each calculation consist of exactly one operation and two numbers

The most outer function represents the left operand, the most inner function represents the right operand

Divison should be integer division. For example, this should return 2, not 2.666666...:

## So the problem I am finding is in the expr function.

I cannot find out how to call the value of operation(number) in my times(a) function, I get "NameError: name 'b' is not defined"

```
def expr(number, operation = None):
    if operation == None:
        return number
    else:
        return operation(number)

def five(operation = None):
    return expr(5, operation)

def seven(operation = None):
    return expr(7, operation)

def times(a):
    return a * b

print(seven(times(five())))
```

I found a solution in javascript, and tried to implement it somehow :

```
var expr = function (number, operation) {
            if (!operation)
                return number;
            return operation(number);
        }

        function zero(operation) { return expr(0, operation) }
        function one(operation) { return expr(1, operation) }
        function two(operation) { return expr(2, operation) }
        function three(operation) { return expr(3, operation) }
        function four(operation) { return expr(4, operation) }
        function five(operation) { return expr(5, operation) }
        function six(operation) { return expr(6, operation) }
        function seven(operation) { return expr(7, operation) }
        function eight(operation) { return expr(8, operation) }
        function nine(operation) { return expr(9, operation) }

        function plus(a) {
            return function (b) {
                return b + a;
            }
        }
        function minus(a) {
            return function (b) {
                return b - a;
            }
        }
        function times(a) {
            return function (b) {
                return a * b;
            }
        }
        function dividedBy(a) {
            return function (b) {
                return b / a;
            }
        }
```

Comment: times method get only 'a' as input not 'b'.. thats why the error.. the code otherwise is very confusing ..

Comment: Alright, thanks for feedback, but perhaps you know what to change? This task is in Codewars, and I am really confused.

Comment: Perhaps you could state the _exact task_? I'm not sure what you even need to do exactly, call a series of curried functions or lambdas that represent numbers _and_ operations, or something?

Comment: Ok thanks @Luke-zhang-04, i will try to research on lambdas tomorrow, I don't even know what they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a lambda, or anonymous function

```py
def times(a):
    return lambda b: a * b
```

Your code should look like this

```py
def expr(number, operation = None):
    if operation:
        return operation(number)
    else:
        return number

def five(operation = None):
    return expr(5, operation)

def seven(operation = None):
    return expr(7, operation)

def times(a):
    return lambda b: a * b

print(seven(times(five())))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, will learn about lambda functions now.

Answer (score -1):

I am slightly confused on what you are trying to accomplish but I will take a shot. I assume by only using functions you want to use functions to print statements instead of using commands such as `print(3*2)`. I have done this before by defining add, subtract, multiply, and divide functions:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

def subtract(x,y):
    return x-y

def multiply(x,y):
    return x*y

def divide(x,y):
    return x/y
```

I than defined variables where I would set x and y to my desired numbers: `a = add(3,3)`. Than I would call a which would add 3 and 3, using my add function. Sorry if that's not what you were looking for, just thought I would try and help.

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but this is not what I needed, I am new to stackoverflow, so I am not used to trying to specify my exact problem. For reference, here is the task I was confused about. https://www.codewars.com/kata/525f3eda17c7cd9f9e000b39/train/python